# Chrome extension sendMessage and asynchronous callback

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I built a Chrome extension using `sendRequest` to send a message from the content page to the popup, and get a callback.

content.js :

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest(data, function (result){
    // here the result should be a boolean
    if (result){
        alert("ok");
    }
});
```

popup.js :

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function (request, sender, callback) {
    // Here I have some asynchronous work
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback(true);
    }, 500);
}
```

All this worked perfectly fine.

But the `sendRequest` is deprecated, and needs to be replaced by `sendMessage` (in order to support Firefox)

I did almost the same thing with `sendMessage` (documentations are exactly the same for [`sendRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Tabs/sendRequest) and [`sendMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Tabs/sendMessage) on Mozilla doc)

content.js :

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(data, function (result) {
    // here the result should be a boolean
    if (result){
        alert("ok");
    }
});
```

popup.js :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, callback) {
    // Here I have some asynchronous work
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback(true);
    }, 500);
}
```

But now, it doesn't work. As soon as the listener function ends, the callback is called with no argument, and the asynchronous function can't send its result.

Is there any way to do the same thing in Firefox ?

Comment: This is not WebExtension specific, Chrome behaves the same way. However, in the Chrome docs this is stated, while WebExtension docs are silent.

Comment: My bad: it's mentioned in the WebExtension docs [under `onMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Runtime/onMessage): _Returns: boolean. Return true from the event listener if you wish to call sendResponse after the event listener returns._

Comment: That's right, it seems to work with the return true, I didn't dig the docs enough. Thanks !